# Alphabetize menu items in K submenus

Tags: kde, menu

How can I alphabetize the items in a submenu of the K menu in Kubuntu (14.10)?  The actions in the "Edit Applications" menu that you get by right-clicking don't include Sort.

Answer (score 3):

Right-click on K, then Edit Applications, then expand the submenu of interest.  Now (here's the nonobvious part) widen the window to show all the possible actions, one of which is Sort (with various kinds of sorting).  If you don't widen the window you'll never see the Sort action.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on K, then go to "settings for K-Menu" and then check "sort by name"